# Copy special character in AWS Redshift

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-redshift

I'm unable to load special character row in AWS Redshift.

Getting an error: String contains invalid or unsupported UTF8 codepoints. Bad UTF8 hex sequence: c8 4d (error 4)

The string causing the problem is: Crème (the è).

For a temporary fix, I am using:

```
copy dev.table (a,
b,
c,
d) from 's3://test-bucket/redshift_data_source/test_data.csv'
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=xxxxxxxxxx;aws_secret_access_key=xxxxxxxxxxxx' CSV delimiter ',' IGNOREHEADER 1 COMPUPDATE OFF acceptinvchars;
```

**acceptinvchars** is accepting them as varchar but putting ? on those characters. How to read them as is?

Comment: Can you open your file in some editor that can show binary values? Or open the file in a UTF-8 aware editor and save it again. The expected UTF-8 code can be found at: http://unicode.scarfboy.com/?s=%C3%A8

Comment: In notepad++ it shows like CRɍE. And in Redshift, while loading, it becomes CR.ME but due to acceptinvchars, it becomes CR?ME.

Comment: You'll need to figure out what format it is actually stored in. Here are some potential methods: [How can I view the binary contents of a file natively in Windows 7? (Is it possible.)](https://superuser.com/q/468456)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution seems to be to convert your source data to UTF-8. It is currently saved using some other encoding.